# Thread.Sleep() in Scheduled Task

Tags: asp.net, windows, multithreading, hosting, sleep

I would like to know if this is possible?

Inside a windows hosting plan, there is a Scheduled Task feature wherein I will place my website's url and run in a certain time.

I want to make it as an email sender function.

If I use Thread.Sleep() inside its loop when the url is called, will this also sleep the whole website?
Can a visitor still use my website even if I use the Thread.Sleep() method?
Or there is other way to do it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a question that should be directed to your hosting provider.

Comment: Does anybody try this before?